# How to prevent overrding in Jinja2 engine for different sections?

Tags: html, flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

I am very new to Flask and I have read related questions but I still don't understand how to fix this problem so any help would be greatly appreciated. Please don't duplicate this question.

I have the following file:

index.html

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block styles %}

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="/static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
<link href="/static/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/agency.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/agency.min.css">

{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}

<body id="page-top">

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">RFJI Protein Database</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        Menu
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{{ url_for('upload')}}">Upload File</a>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Protein Database</a>
          </li>
          </li>
          </li>
          </li>



          <div class="wrap">
            <div class="search">
              <div class="col-lg-11 text-center">
              <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
              <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </ul>


{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

    <header class="masthead">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">
          <div class="intro-lead-in">Welcome to the RFJI Protein Database!</div>
          <div class="intro-heading text-uppercase">It's Nice To Meet You</div>

    <style>
    font-family: Arial;
    </style>

    {% endblock %}

    {% block body %}
    <!-- Services -->
    <section id="services">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Features</h2>
            <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="/static/img/kinase.png" alt="Girl in a onci" style="width:80px;height:90px;">

            </span>
            <h4 class="service-heading">Search Kinases</h4>
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="/static/img/inhibitor.png" alt="Girl in a onci" style="width:80px;height:90px;">
            </span>
            <h4 class="service-heading">Search Kinase Inhibitors</h4>
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">

          <img src="/static/img/upload.png" alt="Girl in a onci" style="width:80px;height:90px;">
            </span>
            <h4 class="service-heading">Import your own dataset</h4>
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    {% endblock %}
```

The problem is that the Jinja2 engine only displays the Services section but ignores everything else. How can I fix this please?. I have added a image on how I want the website to look like it.

[How I want the website to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVAfu.png)

Many Thanks,

Moshi

Comment: Please update the question with contents of `bootstrap/base.html`.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, the whole template is a mess.

- This should be deleted completely, as it doesn't belong in the middle of the template:

```
    <style>
    font-family: Arial;
    </style>
```

- There are multiple `<body>` tags.  In the correct syntax there should be only 1 `<body>` tag, which should probably be part of the `base.html` template.  Towards the end of this file, the corresponding `</body>` tag should also be present.
- Some of the `<div>` tags are not closed properly.

You really need to go back and rearrange this tempate so that each Jinja2 `{% block something %} {% endblock %}` section contains a complete set of tags (for example a full bootstrap div container block which is closed properly before the endblock statement.

Template inheritance is [described fully](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#template-inheritance) in the Jinja2 docs.  I assume you've cut and pasted sections of this template from somewhere else which isn't a problem provided you make sure that important components of the source bootstrap template aren't split up in the wrong places.

Comment: Hi, how can I fix it into proper blocks as I am very new to this, can you give me some examples please?

Comment: But how do I create a new section like in the image please?